# Are there many more irrational numbers than rational?

Tags: number-theory

Does it make sense to say that there are more irrational numbers than rational?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, in the sense of cardinality. In the same sense that one can say that there are more real numbers than there are rationals (or integers; or natural numbers).

The rational numbers are countable, but the irrationals are uncountable.

Comment: In your second sentence, do you mean "more real numbers than there are rationals?"

Comment: @Jonas Kibelbek: Oops; yes. Thanks